# Convert mail raw source into string using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

since weeks I am getting a lot of spam via email, these emails are all different but what they have in common is a hyperlink. Since Apple mail doesn't allow you to create a rule based on raw source but only on body content, I have decided to have one mail rule running an AppleScript. I am trying to create a rule that gets the entire message, convert it to string, check if a specific string is in it and then deletes the message.
My entire script is ready but I am having difficulties on converting "theMessage" into string, I guess that the html code in the email is somehow sending AppleScript crazy.
Do you have any suggestion?

Just to clarify, the error I got so far it's always the following: Can’t make «class mssg» id 349216 of «class mbxp» "[Gmail]/All Mail" of «class mact» id "7B5...." into type string.

Comment: Have you tried to read the `content` rather than the `source` property of a message

Comment: Yes but unfortunately the content only includes what's visible in the email body, instead I need to look for an href which is visible in the raw code

Comment: Then use `text item delimiters` to parse the HTML text

Comment: I'll give it a try, any idea of what character might be breaking it?

Comment: Just to clarify, the error I got so far it's always the following:

Can’t make «class mssg» id 349216 of «class mbxp» "[Gmail]/All Mail" of «class mact» id "7B5...." into type string.

Comment: Most likely, **you tried to coerce the message** to text. You should instead coerce the **source of message**. You should use **as string**